# Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller

Tags: embedded, interrupt, interrupt-handling, interrupted-exception

I been struggling with NVIC, why it is used? and how it is used? 
In my project I'm using

```
 NVIC_IntDisable(NVIC_SSP0); 
 NVIC_ClrPend(NVIC_PIO_0);
 NVIC_IntPri(NVIC_PIO_0, 17);    
 NVIC_IntEnable(NVIC_PIO_0);
```

These are all defined in the `system.c` can anyone explain me why these are used what the use perticular commands. Please mention any good matrial that I can reffer.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific. As it is, your question ask for pretty much all the info, which is in the datasheets.

Comment: Although it may be obvious to an expert that you are referring to the ARM NVIC, your question is vert target specific so you should specify the target.    Also the file system.c is specific you either your application, library or development toolchain so you should probably specify that too.  Ultimately you need to read the ARM technical documentation for details; for a slightly easier introduction perhaps one of Joseph Yiu's books (assuming ARM Cortex-M). However, if you have to ask what the NVIC is for, you probably first need to learn some fundamentals of interrupts and microprocessors 1st.

Answer (score 0):

NVIC is a Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller (similar to PIC on x86 PC).

You can get more info on ARM website
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s01s01.html and also in specific chip datasheets and ARM manuals for the sub-architecture.

Comment: I personally found this blog post very helpful to understand NVIC : https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/08/14/arm-cortex-m-interrupts-and-freertos-part-1/ . It explains in details and in an easy-to-understand way the interrupt system of ARM Cortex-M based systems.

Comment: All this answer does is to state what the OP already knew (which is obvious from reading the question), then drop a link to the manual. The question is in fact likely too broad to be answered in its current form.

Comment: Well, question also asked for "good matrial", which I linked to. I had also asked for clarifications. The other alternative is just downvoting the question, but that seems even less productive.